# Rule-Triggered Script No Longer Running

Tags: vba, email, outlook

A script that has run in the past is now throwing an error when triggered through an Outlook Rule.

The intent is to save the email attachment in a specified folder and loop through the items in that same folder to delete any files from previous dates as well as any image files.

```vb
Public Sub SaveSalesForceReports(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String
Dim sdate As Variant

sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\A6QDCZZ\Documents\SFReporting\Subscribed_Reports\" 'specify the folder where we will store our attachements that have been downloaded from the subscribed email reports
For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
    sdate = MItem.SentOn
    If Format(sdate, "DD-MM-YYYY") = Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY") Then
        oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.FileName
    End If
Next oAttachment

Dim objFSO, objFolder, objfile As Object

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(sSaveFolder)

For Each objfile In objFolder.Files 'deletes older reports and clears extraneous files that may have been downloaded from the email
    If Format(objfile.DateCreated, "DD-MM-YYYY") <> Format(sdate, "DD-MM-YYYY") Then
        Kill objfile
    ElseIf InStr(Dir(objfile), ".png") > 1 Then
        Kill objfile
    End If
Next objfile

End Sub
```

I get the following error:
[image]

Comment: Run a script rules are unreliable. This is a common complaint. Consider a switch to ItemAdd or NewMailEx.

Answer (score 0):

An outlook update disabled the capability to run scripts.
There is a registry hack that allows you to re-enable it as per this:
https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/

If you have done that, then you may need to edit the rule and check that the script is still listed there. Even if it is, I would try to edit the rule and reselect the macro to run.

Comment: Thanks! I already changed the registry to enable the “run a script option.” I have the the ability to enable the “run a script” feature on the Outlook rule, but it errors out for some reason.

Comment: Delete the rule and recreate it. Also check this:
https://forums.slipstick.com/threads/93957-cannot-run-script-from-rule/